# Using Twilio, how can I play a notification (beep) when a caller is placed in hold/unhold?

Tags: twilio

This is my code, is working fine I'm able to place the caller in hold/unhold, but I haven't find a way to notify the operator when the caller is **hold/unhold**, I want to accomplish the same behavior than when a conference begins the systems plays a **"beep"** notification, any ideas on how to accomplish this ? Thanks in advance

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult holdCall(string CallSID, string RoomID)
        {
            CallCenter_InternalEntities db = new CallCenter_InternalEntities();

        Active_Calls_Queue holdCall = db.Active_Calls_Queue.FirstOrDefault();    
        if (holdCall != null)
        {
            //Twilio logic to hold call   
            var accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAccountSid"];
            var authToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"];
            var twilioHoldURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioHoldURL"]; 
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
            var confSID = holdCall.ConferenceSID;
            var callSID = holdCall.Call_SID;
            var result = ParticipantResource.Update(confSID, callSID, hold: true);

            if (result.Hold??false) {
                holdCall.Status = holdCall.Status = "Hold";
                db.SaveChanges();
                //Log
                db.Actions_Log.Add(new Actions_Log("Call Hold", holdCall.Call_ID, "Call", holdCall.OperatorID, DateTime.Now, holdCall.Call_SID));
                db.SaveChanges();
                var data = new { holdCall.Call_SID, HoldDate = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }                
        }
        return Json(-1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way within the Twilio API right now to make conferences beep when participants are put on hold or returned from hold.

I am guessing that you have an interface that you are using to allow the moderator to place a participant on hold. I would recommend returning the result from your `holdCall` method to the client side and updating your interface based on that. You could even play a sound in your client to just your moderator to let them know that the action worked.

Let me know if that helps at all.